# UIImagePickerController cropping image rect is not correct

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a `UIViewController` that holds the image picker:

```
let picker = UIImagePickerController()
```

and I call the image picker like that:

```
private func showCamera() {
    picker.allowsEditing = true
    picker.sourceType = .camera
    picker.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
    picker.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

when I'm done I get a delegate callback like that:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let croppedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
            self.imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            self.imageView.image = croppedImage
            self.dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

and I get the cropping UI after I took the image and in the video you can see the behaviour:

https://youtu.be/OaJnsjrlwF8

As you can see, I can not scroll the zoomed rect to the bottom or top. This behaviour is reproducible on iOS 10/11 on multiple devices.

Is there any way to get this right with `UIImagePickerController`?

Answer (score 0):

No, this component has been bugged for quite some time now. Not only this one with positioning but also the cropped rect is usually incorrect (off by some 20px vertically).

It seems Apple has no interest in fixing it and you should create your own. It is not too much of work. Start by creating a screen that accepts and displays image on scroll view. Then ensure zoom and pan is working (maybe even rotation) which should be all done pretty quickly.

Then the cropping part occurs which is actually done quickest by using view snapshot:

The following will create an image from image view:

```
    func snapshotImageFor(view: UIView) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
            return nil
        }
        view.layer.render(in: context)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
```

Then in your view controller you can do this little trick:

```
    func createSnapshot(inFrame rect: CGRect) -> UIImage? {
        let temporaryView = UIView(frame: rect) // This is a view from which the snapshot will occure
        temporaryView.clipsToBounds = true
        view.addSubview(temporaryView) // We want to put it into hierarchy

        guard let viewToSnap = scrollViewContainer else { return nil } // We want to use the superview of the scrollview because using scroll view directly may have some issues.

        let originalImageViewFrame = viewToSnap.frame // Preserve previous frame
        guard let originalImageViewSuperview = viewToSnap.superview else { return nil } // Preserve previous superview
        guard let index = originalImageViewSuperview.subviews.index(of: viewToSnap) else { return nil } // Preserve view hierarchy index

        // Now change the frame and put it on the new view
        viewToSnap.frame = originalImageViewSuperview.convert(originalImageViewFrame, to: temporaryView)
        temporaryView.addSubview(viewToSnap)

        // Create snapshot
        let croppedImage = snapshotImageFor(view: temporaryView)

        // Put everything back the way it was
        viewToSnap.frame = originalImageViewFrame // Reset frame
        originalImageViewSuperview.insertSubview(viewToSnap, at: index) // Reset superview
        temporaryView.removeFromSuperview() // Remove the temporary view

        self.croppedImage = croppedImage

        return croppedImage
    }
```

There are some downsides to this procedures like doing everything on main thread but for your specific procedure this should not be a problem at all.

You might at some point want some control of the image output size. You can do that easiest by modifying snapshot image to include custom scale:

```
func snapshotImageFor(view: UIView, scale: CGFloat = 0.0) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, scale)
```

Then you would for instance call `snapshotImageFor(view: view, scale: expectedWidth/view.bounds.width)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've filed a bugreport at bugreport.apple.com and you can see it here: http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=4932871525498880

Please duplicate the bugreport!